# How to convert int array to List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>?

Tags: c#, linq, keyvaluepair

I need to convert an integer array to a list of KeyValuePair where the string can be an empty string. What would be an efficient and elegant way to do this?

So from this:

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

to this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
pairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, ""));
pairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, ""));
pairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, ""));
```

Obviously there are many ways to do this, starting from a for loop but I'm looking for preferably a single line of code, perhaps a linq statement if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var res = ints.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(x, "")).ToList();
```

Or also possible:

```
var dict = ints.ToDictionary(x => x, x => "")
```

Which will create a dictionary which basically IS a list of KeyValue-pairs.

Comment: dictionary NOT is a list of KeyValue pairs, it just `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> pairs = ints.Select(i => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, i.ToString())).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, just accepted the previous answer with a similar solution, this works perfectly as well.

Comment: this will produce `{ { 1, "1" }, { 2, "2" } ... }`, not empty emptry strings for the values.